# How do I use MATLAB in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to write programs in MATLAB(mex files) by using Visual Studio 2010?
If yes, then is it possible without installing MATLAB application.

Comment: what is a 'matlab program'? A matlab-script? mex file? stand-alone?

Comment: You can write and compile mex files in Visual Studio, and you can use them on a computer with no Matlab installed, if you install the  (free) Matlab runtime, and compile a standalone app using the Matlab compiler. However you must have a computer with Matlab installed in order to compile a mex file or compiling a standalone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write MATLAB programs in any tool you like that includes a text editor, including Visual Studio or just Notepad.

But to run them you need MATLAB. There is a free package called Octave that is partly compatible with MATLAB and will run many basic MATLAB programs, but not all.

Comment: So theres no shorcut. Ill have to download the program right?

Comment: If you want to run MATLAB files but don't want to buy MATLAB, you can try Octave. But if they are not compatible with Octave, or if Octave is not suitable for another reason (e.g. you need support or training) then yes, you'll need to get MATLAB.